# Index match with partial text and multiple matches

Tags: excel, indexing, text, match, partial

I have a dynamic table with input data which i am trying to gather specific data from. The table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayTIh.png)

What i am trying to do is to retrieve the name of the different contracts based on a partial text. So in cell A1 (formula cell) i want to use index & match on the above table, and find the contract which has "ER" in it. As you can see there are multiple contracts thats named "ER", and this is the only fixed part. (ERZ2, ERZ3 and ERM3, these data will change, but there will never be more than three "ERs" at once.

In cell A1 i want the first ER-contract, and in A2 and A3 etc. i want the next ER-contracts. If my criteria is that the cells in my input table contains "ER", then i only get the first match, which is ERZ2. Which formula can i use in the different output cells (A1, A2 and A3) so that i get all the ER-contracts (ERZ2, ERZ3 and ERM3)?

Many thanks for help in advance!

Comment: With ms365 or Excel2021 you can use `FILTER()`. Can you share your attempted formula, and let us know what version of Excel you have. It would also be great if you can include your data as markdown-sample data so we don't have to recreate the data from a picture.

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 so i dont have the filter function. I have used the following formula as of now: =INDEX(AX29:AX100;MATCH("ER"&"*";AX29:AX100;0)). Then i only get the first contract (ERZ2). Sorry i dont know how to include it as markdown sample data. Thanks for reply :)